# Зачем нужен <T> перед void в описании метода?

Tags: java, generics

Есть метод:

```
public static <T> void fill(List<T> list, T val) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
        list.set(i, val); 
    }
```

Зачем этот `<T>` перед `void` стоит? Что он делает? Ничего же не возвращается - зачем оно тут? И главное как соотносится этот `<T> void...` с тем что в параметрах `(List<T> list, T val)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь `<T>` относится не к результату метода (`void`), а к входным параметрам (`List<T> list, T val`). Просто так принято, что переменная типа вводится после модификаторов и перед возвращаемым типом. Это является особенностью обобщенного метода.

Comment: Но она же уже указана в параметрах. Разве этого не достаточно?

Comment: @Павел, нет, этого не достаточно - такая конструкция является особенностью обобщенного метода.

Comment: @Павел А если у Вас будет такой метод `public static <T> void fill(T val)` тогда как?

Comment: А если я напишу так <T extends Number> void fill1(List<T> list, T val){} это можно будет понимать так что те <T> которые в параметрах указаны тоже теперь extends Number или они разные?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а к чему этот вопрос?

Comment: @Павел да, они "тоже теперь `extends Number`".

Comment: @Павел Этот вопрос к тому, что как в этом случае определить, что Т это обобщенный тип, если не указывать его перед возвращаемым типом?

Comment: Ага кажется поймал! Тоесть в параметрах я не могу писать (List<T extends Number> list, T val) это мне компилятор не разрешает, зато я могу это перед возвращаемым значением определить... правильно?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а ведь вопрос задал я, а не Павел. Клонил я к тому, что чем же хуже `List<T> list` для примера? Та же проблема ведь, что и в случае `T val`. Вот мне и интересно, почему вы акцентировали внимание именно на таком примере.

Comment: @Павел прочитайте ответ на вопрос (в том числе пример в нём), который я привел в "возможный дубликат". Быть может, вам станет понятнее, зачем вообще нужно это указывать.

Comment: Да я уже прочитал там совсем в общем про то что это обобщенный тип. А я хочу понять как этот <T> перед возвращаемым значением соотносится с <T> который в параметрах

Comment: @Павел `public static <Один_и_тот_же_тип> void test(List<Один_и_тот_же_тип> list, Один_и_тот_же_тип val) { }` - так вам понятнее? Так код, кстати, компилируется и вполне себе работает.

Answer (score 4):

Согласно спецификации Java SE 8 Edition (8.4 Method Declarations) метод определяется следующим образом

```
MethodDeclaration: 
    {MethodModifier} MethodHeader MethodBody

MethodHeader: 
    Result MethodDeclarator [Throws] 
    TypeParameters {Annotation} Result MethodDeclarator [Throws
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

То есть в вашем объявлении метода

```
public static <T> void fill(List<T> list, T val)
              ^^^
```

выделенная часть - это объявление параметров типов `TypeParameters` для обобщенных методов. То есть эта часть объявления обобщенного метода служит для объявления переменных типов, используемых в определении метода.

Объявление вашего метода можно подробнее расписать следующим образлм

```
public static     <T>            void    fill(List<T> list, T val)
MethodModifier   TypeParameters  Result  MethodDeclarator
```